6 V AC conversion
I would like to know how I can get DC from the 6 V AC alternator on my moped.
I have a step up booster so I think I can use any DC voltage I get but I need the DC voltage in the first place. I am just trying to connect an LED light. Also, I can't seem to figure out how to measure amperage.
I don't have any special tools as I am only 16 years old but I'm planning to buy some because I enjoy making small projects like these.
The only thing I really have is a multimeter.

Does the alternator have two wires or is there only one and the other is the machine metal itself?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The alternator has 2 wires. One for the power itself and one as ground. The moped doesnt have any battery or any way to convert to DC by itself.

To convert AC to DC requires a rectifier circuit (typically full wave diode bridge) and a filter (typically capacitors).  Does the moped have 6V starter battery?  If yes, there is already a rectifier and DC regulator between the raw alternator output and the starter battery to keep the battery charged. You can attach your DC booster input to the 6V battery wires, which is a DC power source.
With a multimeter, likely can measure the DC voltage at the battery terminals. The DC voltage should increase after starting the engine while charging.
To measure DC current, requires a meter with a DC Amps mode (found on many multi-meters, but not simple ones with only voltage and resistance measurement capability). With power off, open the circuit path/wire you desire to measure and insert the meter in series.  Most handheld multimeters can only handle up to 10 Amps, which is likely sufficient to measure current in a bright LED circuit but not sufficient to measure engine starter current.  So don't measure all the current in/out of moped battery terminal while starting or running engine (charging).

It doesnt have battery or any convertor itself. I am trying to come up with ways to power LED light because the light i have right now is gonna get me killed :D I thought about boosting the alternator eith bigger coils. There are 4 coils: 1 is for the spark and the other 3 are for the lights. I thought about buying stronger coils and then using 12v ac converter from aliexpress but as i said already, the current alternator supports only 6v and i dont know if i can even upgrade the coils.

Does the existing lamp run from the 6V AC output?   Is the LED you want to use already 12Vdc module or can you choose a 6V LED module instead and skip the the step-up booster?   You could build cheap rectifier/filter like this one https://www.ebay.com/itm/126505369340  to get DC out from the 6 VAC input.   PCB could be optional if solder parts directly together like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwFoBp63L7s
